# htaccess redirect to different page on 403 Forbidden Error

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess

Can't find this for the life of me. We have the indexes protected so if someone goes to `CDNdomain.com/1/` they won't see anything unless they do `CDNdomain.com/1/something.jpg`. When they visit `/1/` they are presented with a 403 Forbidden error. What I would like to do is when they are shown a 403 Forbidden error to instead redirect them to `ourRealdomain.com`.

Any ideas?

Comment: What directive(s) is causing the 403? Is it just no index/autoindex off?

Comment: Yeah I'm just doing Options -Indexes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this in the htaccess file in the document root of `CDNdomain.com`:

```
RewriteEngine On
# make sure this is the right host
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} cdndomain.com$ [NC]
# make sure this is a request for an existing directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
# redirect
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://ourRealdomain.com/ [L,R=301]
```

Note that this will also redirect `/`: `http://CDNdomain.com/` to `http://ourRealdomain.com/`. If you want to avoid that, change the regex match from `^(.*)$` to `^(.+)$`. If you want to put these rules in the vhost config for the **CDNdomain.com**, add a slash after the `^`: `^/(.+)$`.

Comment: Hm.. That didn't seem to do anything. It's still showing 403's.

Comment: Edit: Nevermind.. I must have done something wrong.. it works now. Thank you.